# How to omit .default from named module imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I'm struggling to config my import and exports so that I don't have to use `.default` when I want to select what I'm exporting instead of the module.

How it's exported.

```
import * as Icon from './components/1_atom/icon/svgicon'
import * as Button from './components/1_atom/button/button'

export { Icon, Button }

export default Icon;
```

How it's imported

```
import { Button, Icon } from '@philipaarseth/simple-components';
```

Here's what I get if I console.log the button

[image: Module object]

Is there a way I can change how I export the modules so that I couldn't have to use `Button.default`?

Comment: Why are you using `import * as Icon from` instead of `import Icon from` if you want the default export? `* as` is explicitly asking for the whole module object instead of a specific export.

Comment: Yeah, that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to loganfsmyth's the comment:

The answer was simply to change

`import * as Icon from`
to
`import Icon from`